# Two azure tenants in one o365 tenant mail domain

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

Is it possible to use the same o365 tenant with one mail domain in two azure tenants?
For example:

- contoso.com has o365 and azure tenant for @contoso.com
- mylab.com has o365 and azure tenant for @mylab.com

Now the mylab users should get a @contoso.com mailadress.

Both tenants are filled from an onpremise active directory with Azure AD Connect. A forest trust of the local active directories is possible.

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: A custom domain can only exist in a single Office 365 tenant. To my knowledge it is not possible to share an SMTP namespace between two different Office 365 tenants.

Comment: You'd have to add them as contacts in the contoso.com tenant and configure forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

One public internet domain is connected to only one Azure AD tenant at one time.
You can have two tenants, each one with its own public internet domain, and then you can invite user to be used as external/guest users in another organization/tenant.

So, userA@contoso.com can invite userB@mylab.com as external/guest to be present also in contoso.com AD, and vice-versa.